# Minimize a piecewise linear, convex function with scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I want to find the minimum of a function which is piecewise linear, convex and differentiable at all but a finite number of points. What `scipy.optimize.minimize` method is appropriate to find a fast solution to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function is piecewise linear and convex, the minimum must be at one of the points where the linear pieces are connected. There is no need for a derivative, you should be able to use a binary search.

Comment: ...and then check if the two linear pieces joining thus found minimum have zero slopes.